# Unable to Pass Data between Activities through Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass data between activities

**Activity one**: Inputs phone number and passes it to the next activity

**Activity Two**: Gets phone number through intent and sends OTP to that number

First Activity Code:

```
public class PhoneVerification extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText edMobileNumber;
private Button btnContinue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_verification);

    edMobileNumber = findViewById(R.id.edMobileNumber);
    btnContinue = findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);



    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String phoneNumber = edMobileNumber.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneVerification.this, OTPVerificationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("phone",phoneNumber);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}}
```

Second Activity Code :

```
public class OTPVerificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTvResend, mTvTimer;
private ImageView mIvBack;
String verificationCodeSentToUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_o_t_p_verification);

    
    mTvResend = findViewById(R.id.tvResend);
    mTvTimer = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
   
    // OTP Process
    String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
    sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);
    Toast.makeText(this, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Phone", "onCreate: " + phoneNumber);

    // Code Resend
    new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTvTimer.setText(String.format("%d seconds left",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTvTimer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTvResend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();}}
```

Problem is that I didn't get the phone number that I passed from the first activity

Comment: _sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);_ is this API call?

Comment: Yes, this method sends the OTP . Sending OTP is the next tep I commented the method call and just checked the toast and log .. phone number was not there.

Comment: Comment _sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);_ this line and check it again

Answer (score 0):

1st activity use this way to send data

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneVerification.this, OTPVerificationActivity.class);
 String value ="111111";
 intent.putExtra("phone", value);
```

2nd activity where you receive the data

```
    String result;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (savedInstance != null) {
            result= (String) savedInstance.getSerializable("phone");
    } else {
          if(extras != null) {
                   result= extras.getString("phone");
         }
    }
```

Comment: What is savedInstance.. I don't get any suggestions in the IDE. Instead, savedInsatncestate was there but that also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

First check if number is not null then go to the next activity other wise stay in the page you have mistake ia you have to not check in button click event these kind of condition so obviously they didnot get number in second activity....